# How to negate/ "reverse mean" this search - that is "!" the meaning

Tags: shell, testing, if-statement, find, negate

```
if [[ -n  $(find $path  -name "$string*")  ]]
then
    <stuff>
else

<stuff>

fi
```

I want to reverse the above search like

```
 if [[ ! -n  $(find $path  -name "$string*")  ]]
then
    <stuff>
else

<stuff>

fi
```

But it wont allow this because here I am checking the find commands output 
any clue.thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the search in find itself using:

```
find "$path" ! -name "$string*"
```

btw this is also valid:

```
[[ ! -n $(find $path -name "$string*") ]]
```

Or else you can use `-z`:

```
[[ -z $(find $path -name "$string*") ]]
```

Comment: I used the # 2 one but the mistake I made was [[! and it did not recognize the !- Kept 'no space' for 'space' . But EVEN after that was fixed the equivalence is lost `[[ ! -n $(find $path -name "$string*") ]]` then echo "Yah" else echo "Nada"` . will always yield Yah . So ! n does not negate it at all  and that is probably because we are checking for the number . `! -name` is fabulous TY anubhava.